# How Can I run a Test Script written in Robotium in to a device cloud?

Tags: robotium, automated-tests

I would like to know is it possible to run my script written in Robotium to work in a device cloud like Perfectomobile or Device anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[testdoid](http://testdroid.com/) allows you to run robotium in the cloud they also have there own extensions to robotium to increase functionality. There are other options out there I am sure and many others that offer support for tests using different frameworks such as calabash.

Comment: Do you have a link where this extension is referenced/explained? I can't seem to find this extension you're mentioning.

Comment: i linked to testdroid in my answer (just click where it says testdroid) http://calaba.sh/ is calabashes address, they both have pretty good documentation!